# How do I print an extremely long but narrow image (png file)?

Tags: windows, printing, images, graphics, png

Someone asked me to print out an entire conversation thread they had on a messaging app, graphics and all. (Don't ask.) The app is Viber; neither the iphone nor desktop app has a print function, and there isn't a browser web app that I can find.

Using a screen capture app, I managed to capture a scrolling window of the thread, resulting in a roughly 2000 x 63000 pixels png. Great! Except: how in the world do I actually print out this monstrosity? I'm on Windows and I've tried paint, paint.net, and paint shop pro, but all these programs want to shrink and fit the image on 1 page, or crop it and just print the first or last bit. I need to somehow paginate this humongous long image and print it out into pages like a word doc.

Any suggestion on how I can do this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you're comfortable with the command line, does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/143498/how-to-divide-an-image-in-x-equal-parts
I know you've tagged this as `windows`, but you should be able to download a Windows version of ImageMagick

Comment: thanks. I can handle that. It's not going to be pretty as it's going to cut things in the middle. But that was always going to be the case unless I am willing to spend time manually cropping.